# Mockito: How to mock spring special DI that the injected object doesn't have no-arg constructor

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm using `Mockito 3.4.6` in unit test, actually, i have integrated Mockito to my unit test and it works well. While, now i need to optimize some unit test, it's a **special dependency injection** that the injected object **doesn't have no-arg constructor**, I tried `@Spy` but it didn't work.

**My Test:** I tried 1. `@Spy`; 2. `@Spy` with setting instance using `= getDtInsightApi()`; 3. `@Spy` with `@InjectMocks`, all of tests are failed. As Mockito docs said, seems it can't work for this case.

> @InjectMocks Mockito will try to inject mocks only either by constructor injection,
> setter injection, or property injection in order and as described below.

Also if only use `@Spy`, it will throw `MockitoException`:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Failed to release mocks

This should not happen unless you are using a third-part mock maker

...
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unable to initialize @Spy annotated field 'api'.
Please ensure that the type 'DtInsightApi' has a no-arg constructor.
...
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Please ensure that the type 'DtInsightApi' has a no-arg constructor.
```

See my **pseudocode as below**:

*configure class:*

```
@Configuration
public class SdkConfig {

    @Resource
    private EnvironmentContext environmentContext;

    @Bean(name = "api")
    public DtInsightApi getApi() {
     
        DtInsightApi.ApiBuilder builder = new DtInsightApi.ApiBuilder()
                    .setServerUrls("sdkUrls")
        return builder.buildApi();
    }
}
```

*`DtInsightApi` class* with no public no-arg constructor and get instance  by its inner class

```
public class DtInsightApi {
    private String[] serverUrls;

    DtInsightApi(String[] serverUrls) {
        this.serverUrls = serverUrls;
    }
    
    // inner class
    public static class ApiBuilder {
        String[] serverUrls;

        public ApiBuilder() {
        }
        ...code...

        public DtInsightApi buildApi() {
           return new DtInsightApi(this.serverUrls);
        }
    }

    ...code...

}
```

*unit test class:*

```
public Test{
   
   @Autowired
   private PendingTestService service;

   @Spy
   private Api api = getDtInsightApi();

   @Mock
   private MockService mockService;

   @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // open mock
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        // i use doReturn(...).when() for @Spy object
        Mockito.doReturn(mockService).when(api)
                   .getSlbApiClient(MockService.class);
        Mockito.when(mockService.addOrUpdate(any(MockDTO.class)))
                   .thenReturn(BaseObject.getApiResponseWithSuccess());
    }

    public DtInsightApi getDtInsightApi () {
        return new DtInsightApi.ApiBuilder()
                .setServerUrls(new String[]{"localhost:8080"})
                .buildApi();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        service.update();
    }
}
```

*`PendingTestService`:*

```
@Service
public class PendingTestService{
   
   @Autowired
   DtInsightApi api;

   public void update() {
      // here mockService isn't the object i mocked
      MockService mockService = api.getSlbApiClient(MockService.class);
      mockService.update();
   }
}
```

**Question:** How to mock the DI object DtInsightApi which doesn't have **no-arg constructor**.

Comment: I believe the way to go is `Mockito.mock(DtInsightApi.class)`. And then you stub all the invoked methods.

Comment: You could try mocking the builder class and the related methods. Thus, with this in place you could very well mock the builder's `build` method and return a purely mocked instance of  `DtInsightApi`. By the way you mention that you tried spying on this but it didn't work. What was the problem you noticed?

Comment: Hi akortex91,  i debugged `MockService mockService = api.getSlbApiClient(MockService.class);` and found mockService  instance isn't a mockito proxy object.

Comment: @naimdjon, after `DtInsightApi api = Mockito.mock(DtInsightApi.class);` what should i do to inject it to spring?

Comment: @KDFinal you will have to instantiate the service with the mock or create a test config that has a @Bean annotation that gives an instance of `DtInsightApi`.

Comment: I updated my solution and it works well with a little change. @naimdjon

Comment: @akortex91 had solution to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checked Spring docs about unit test, I found a solution using `@MockBean`.

Spirng docs:https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

According to Spring docs, you can use **`@MockBean` to mock a bean inside your `ApplicationContext`**, so i can use `@MockBean` to mock `DtInsightApi`.

> It’s sometimes necessary to mock certain components within your application context when running tests. For example,
> you may have a facade over some remote service that’s unavailable during development. Mocking can also be useful when
> you want to simulate failures that might be hard to trigger in a real environment.
>
> Spring Boot includes a `@MockBean` annotation that can be used to define a Mockito mock for a bean inside your `ApplicationContext`.
> You can use the annotation to add new beans, or replace a single existing bean definition. The annotation can be used directly on test classes,
> on fields within your test, or on `@Configuration` classes and fields. When used on a field, the instance of the created mock will also be injected.
> Mock beans are automatically reset after each test method.

**My Solution:** Use `@MockBean` and `BDDMockito.given(...).willReturn(...)`, use
`@Qualifier("api")` to specify the bean name because `@MockBean` injected by class type, if you have same class beans, you need to specify bean name.

**My code in test class:**

```
public class Test{
    @MockBean
    @Qualifier("api")
    private DtInsightApi api;

   @Mock
   private MockService mockService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // open mock
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        BDDMockito.given(this.api.getSlbApiClient(MockService.class)).willReturn(mockService);
    }

    @Autowired
    private PendingTestService service;


    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        service.update();
    }
}
```

Debug the mockService you can see mockService instance is generated by `Mockito`, mock succeed.

**You can also refer to Spring docs example:** mock `RemoteService` in unit test.

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.*;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.*;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.*;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTests {

    @MockBean
    private RemoteService remoteService;

    @Autowired
    private Reverser reverser;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
        // RemoteService has been injected into the reverser bean
        given(this.remoteService.someCall()).willReturn("mock");
        String reverse = reverser.reverseSomeCall();
        assertThat(reverse).isEqualTo("kcom");
    }

}
```